# Xen Swap File/Memory

Tags: vps, xen

Does anyone know if swap memory from a Xen container uses actual RAM from the node, or does it use disk space on the node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses disk. Because of the silly 30 char limit, I'll add that you can easily find this out by looking at your Xen configuration and partition layout.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm not the one setting up the actual containers, as a friend is doing it.

Comment: No worries. Keep in mind though, faking swap with ram would completely defeat its point. You might as well give the server extra ram and no swap instead.